# C++: Cross correlation with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have to implement a cross correlation of two arrays in C++, and I think that could be do with template matching in OpenCV.

I started with a simple case:

```
    double telo [3] ={0,1,2};
    Mat prueba(1,3,CV_64F,telo);

    double telo2[3] = {0,1,2};
    Mat prueba2(1,3,CV_64F,telo2);

    Mat result(1,50,CV_64F);


    matchTemplate(prueba,prueba2,result,CV_TM_CCORR);
```

But it crashes, how can i do this? it is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error message reveals that only `CV_8U` or `CV_32F` types are used. The code runs with `float` types. If you want to use double precision, you'll have to built your own function.

Working code:

```
    float telo [3] ={0,1,2};
    Mat prueba(1,3,CV_32F,telo);
    float telo2[3] = {0,1,2};
    Mat prueba2(1,3,CV_32F,telo2);
    Mat result;
    matchTemplate(prueba,prueba2,result,CV_TM_CCORR);
```

Assertion messages explain most of the times the situation. Check the console output next time.